# Android - Update to latest spinner style

Tags: android, styles, spinner

How do I get my Android app to use the latest style guidelines?  For example, my spinners look like this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Is there something I can update so that all input elements across the app use the latest style (without having to define custom styles?)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can just add this to your activity in your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
```

Here's the full example:

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.bip_test.activities.ShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_share"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

Comment: I suggest to add the reference to the theme in the Application tag, so it's applied to all the activities:
<application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">